# addEventListener to an element, with the element itself as parameter

Tags: javascript, onclick, this, bind, addeventlistener

First of all, sorry if the title isn't the best one, I couldn't find a better one.

How can I set a function as clickEvent for a Div using javascript, and at the same time also set the parameter of the function, to be the Div itself?
For example:

I have a **HTML** file that has:

```
<span id='parent'>
    <div class='child'></div>
</span>
```

And a **JS** file where I have the following code:

```
var el = document.getElementById("parent").getElementsByClassName("child")[0];
el.onclick = someFuntion(this);
```

But the thing is, I want that the `this` paramenter refer to the `div.child`, so that when I click the Div it should pass itself as a parameter, as a DOM element, making me able to use it inside of `someFuntion(element)` just like any other DOM element: `element#id`, for example.

Solutions tried:

```
el.addEventListener("click", someFuntion(event), false);
el.addEventListener("click", someFuntion(this), false);
el.addEventListener("click", someFuntion(el), false);
$("#parent #child").bind("click", someFuntion(this));
el.onclick = someFuntion(divIntoSpan);
```

**SOLUTION:**
    `el.onclick = someFuntion;`

```
function someFunction(e){
    if(e.target){
        //remember to use "e.target" from here on, instead of only "e"
        //e.id (error: undefined); e.target.id (correct)
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not passing a function pointer when you have `el.onclick = someFuntion(this);`. You're setting the value of `el.onlick` to the results of the evaluation of someFunction(this);

Comment: Just a note to your markup. The [`span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/span.html) element is only permitted to have [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#phrasing-content) which the `div` element isn't.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Solution

Just do `el.addEventListener("click", someFunction);` <- not `someFunction()`

and then use `event.target`

```
function someFunction(e) {
   if(e.target) ...
}
```

### Alternative solution

If you like @JaromandaX's solution, you could simplify it to

```
el.addEventListener("click",someFunction.bind(null,el));
```

Note that [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) returns function. This example should clarify it:

```
function someFunction(el) {
  // if used with bind below, the results are:
  console.log(this); // "This is it!"
  console.log(el); // the clicked element
}

a.addEventListener("click",someFunction.bind("This is it!",a));
```

### Advice

- `someFunction` is the function itself
- `someFunction()` is what the function returns

If you want to be a good coder, you shouldn't be satisfied with *It works!*. It is worthy to spend some time to find out **why** it works. Without this step you can't be sure if your code doesn't contain hidden bugs in some cases.

What you have in *Solutions tried* is [Programming by permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_permutation) which is an antipattern - I highly recommend reading this great wiki [article about antipatterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

Comment: @alexluz I updated the answer to be more useful to you. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

if, for some reason you must do it the way you want

```
el.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
    someFunction(e.target);
}, false);
```

but the answer given by Jan Turoň is the preferred way

Comment: Your solution also worked, I marked the one above for being a cleaner code, as you said. But it is always good to know that there are many ways of doing this. Thank you!