# How to refer to the value of an input that was created dynamically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a table of inputs.
[image]

When an input is changed, the change event should trigger a function ( `updatePlanner()`) to change the data in the underlying data. Here is where I create the table.

```
function tableCreate(columns, rows){
    var body = document.getElementById('planBuilderTable'),
        tbl  = document.createElement('table');

    // header code removed

    for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        var tr = tbl.insertRow();

        var week = 0;

        for(var j = 0; j < columns * 3; j++){
            var td = tr.insertCell();
            td.style.height = "26px";

            switch(j % 3){
                case 0:
                    var currItem = document.createElement('input');
                    currItem.value = builerObj.dataArray[2][week][i][0];
                    currItem.addEventListener("change", function(){
                        updatePlanner(this.value, week, i, 0);  //<-----------THIS IS MY ISSUE
                    });
                    break;
                case 1:
                    var currItem = document.createElement('input');
                    currItem.value = builerObj.dataArray[2][week][i][1];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    var currItem = document.createElement('button');
                    currItem.style.height = "26px";
                    currItem.style.border = "none";
                    currItem.style.padding = "0px";
                    currItem.style.display = "block";
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    if (builerObj.dataArray[2][week][i][2] == 1){
                        span.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok box";
                    } else{
                        span.className = "glyphicon box";
                    }
                    currItem.appendChild(span);
                    week += 1;
                    break;
            }

            currID = i.toString() + "-" + j.toString()
            currItem.setAttribute("id", currID);
            currItem.style.width = "40px";


            td.appendChild(currItem);
            td.style.border = '1px solid black';

        }
    }
    body.innerHTML = "";
    body.appendChild(tbl);
}
```

As you can see I am trying to use `this.value`, but that isn't returning a value. I've also tried assigning the ID earlier and refer to it:

```
        ...
        currID = i.toString() + "-" + j.toString();

            switch(j % 3){
                case 0:

                    var currItem = document.createElement('input');
                    currItem.setAttribute("id", currID);
                    currItem.value = builerObj.dataArray[2][week][i][0];
                    currItem.addEventListener("change", function(){
                        updatePlanner(document.getElementById(currID).value, week, i, 0);
                    });
                    break;
                    ...
```

Comment: Are you averse to using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)?

Comment: Define "isn't working". In any case, you don't even need a `this` reference, you can use `currItem.value` if nothing else. But the value of `this` depends a lot on the context of how you're creating the function etc.

Comment: @FelesMortis I'm fine with jQuery

Comment: @DaveNewton the this.value and currItem.value do not return a value. I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of Undefined"

Comment: Provide more details on the error. Is the error in `updatePlanner`? Is `currItem`'s value correct when you set it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [addEventListener to an element, with the element itself as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272118/addeventlistener-to-an-element-with-the-element-itself-as-parameter)

Comment: You could assign each element an id as well as a common class to all of them as you create them. Use the class as the trigger and the id to identify which specific element triggered it.

Comment: The only location in this example where the error could be thrown is `builerObj.dataArray[2][week][i]`, which doesn't have anything to do with how you bind the handler. Not sure if we can help you if you don't provide a *runnable* example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @SunKnight0 I tried that, as you can see in my edit

Comment: @Nate May I do all this with JQuery not vanilla JavaScript so I wouldn't know why it is not working for you, sorry.

Comment: I believe `this.value` works just fine, and your issue is actually with `week` and `i`: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196).

Comment: Argh, I accidentally undid my upvote on @FelixKling's comment.  Agreed!  Nothing wrong with your use of `this`, as it's within the event handler, so it refers to the input that changed.

Answer (score 0):

this.value returns the correct value, but the other parameters, week and i, don't have the values you expect. You want them to have the values at the time the listener was **added**, but instead, they have the values at the time the listener was **executed**. To solve this, you can store these values as attributes in the input tag and retrieve them later on, like this:

```
    $(currItem).attr("data-week", week);
    $(currItem).attr("data-i", i);
    currItem.addEventListener("change", function(){
         var week_value = $(this).attr("data-week");
         var i_value = $(this).attr("data-i");
         updatePlanner(this.value, parseInt(week_value), parseInt(i_value), 0);
    }, false);
```

Comment: What's wrong with the OP's approach using `this`?  How does it solve the problem?

Comment: I have completely changed my answer.

Comment: *"The image in your question shows that the input fields are actually checkboxes."* What makes you think the inputs correspond to the checkboxes and not the text inputs next to them? The code certainly doesn't generate checkboxes, nowhere I can see `currItem.type = 'checkbox';`? Also if you look closely, the checkboxes in the image are actually buttons with a special glyph.

Comment: Again, I have completely changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you could be looking for here.
The easiest is to add the event argument to the callback function like so:

```
currItem.addEventListener("change", function(e){
  updatePlanner(e.target.value, week, i, 0);
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with the OP's approach using `this`? How does it solve the problem?