# How to bind the event listener to a specific div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a script that executes some action based on an event(keydown/up) bound to the `document`(at the moment).

When some key is pressed along with `shift-key(e.g shift + a)`, some action is triggered.

It is working except that I want to bind the event listener to a specific `div` element.

If I have the following **HTML** content, why is it not possible to bind an event listener to the outermost `div` element with the id attribute?

```
<div id="some-id" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
  :
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
    :
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
      :
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can bind an onclick event listener to this div. Is that what u want?

Comment: Doesn't get much more trivial than this. What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: I am trying to bind keydown/up event to the div. I did something like `$('#some-id').bind`... to bind the events.

Comment: You mention "it's working" but there's no javascript code. Would you mind sharing a minimal sample of what's working?

Comment: You have `position:absolute` in outermost `div` which cause element to get no width and height even though there are contents inside it. In order to make it work, add a height and width.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [addEventListener to an element, with the element itself as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272118/addeventlistener-to-an-element-with-the-element-itself-as-parameter)

Comment: @stealththeninja I have seen the post you are referring and tested the solution suggested, but it did not work. As you can see, the content structure is quite different from mine.

Answer (score 1):

- Set `tabindex` to your div to `zero`
- `Focus` control on your div on document load
- Capture your keys down/ups

Try running demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#some-id").focus();
 shifted = false;
 $("#some-id").bind("keydown keyup", function(e) { 
   switch(e.type) {
    case "keydown":
      console.log(e.key);
      if (e.key === "Shift") {
          shifted = true; 
      }
      break;
    case "keyup":
      console.log(e.key);
      if (e.key === "A" && shifted === true) {
        console.log("Do your action")
      }
      shifted = false;
      break;
  
  }
 
 });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some-id" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; border: solid 1px" tabindex="0" >
my div
</div>
```

Comment: Where does the `shifted` come from?

Comment: @d-_-b as per your question and my understanding, correct me if I am wrong, you're trying to capture 2 keys simultaneously, that's why you have to capture `shift` on keydown and the other key `A` on `keyup`

Comment: I see, is there any side effect by setting `tabindex=0`?

Comment: I tried it and it works on the very first load as explicitly calling the `focus ()`, but once the focus is moved, again forcing the focus set to the `#some-d` element is required for the key events to be picked up

Answer (score 0):

It is because your div is empty so it is not taking any width or height so no events are triggered on any of the divs. Try adding some content to the div. Or Try setting the `min-height` and `min-width` properties of any of the innermost div.

```js
document.getElementById('some-id').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('The click is working')
})
```

```html
<div id="some-id" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; min-width: 100vw; min-height: 100vh"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I omitted the contents of divs. There are contents in the actual HTML.